# How can I get all the text content before the word bookmark by java?

Tags: java, aspose

I want to get all the text content before a bookmark, but i don't know how to do it.
I have used the "extractContent" method in aspose.word,but didn’t get the correct result.
Looking forward to your reply, thanks.

```
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
        builder.moveToDocumentStart();
        Run startRun = new Run(doc, "start");
        builder.insertNode(startRun);
        Run endRun = new Run(doc, "end");
        builder.moveToBookmark(signBookMark.getName());
        builder.insertNode(endRun);
        ArrayList extractedNodesInclusive = extractContent(startRun, endRun, true);
        Document dstDoc = generateDocument(doc, extractedNodesInclusive);
        String result = dstDoc.getRange().getText();
        log.info("result == "+ result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get text representation of all the content that exists before a particular bookmark in Word document by using the following code of [Aspose.Words for Java](https://products.aspose.com/words/java/) API:

```
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\input.doc");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.startBookmark("bm");
BookmarkEnd end = builder.endBookmark("bm");

Bookmark bookmark = doc.getRange().getBookmarks().get("sign_test");
bookmark.getBookmarkStart().getParentNode().insertBefore(end, bookmark.getBookmarkStart());

System.out.println(doc.getRange().getBookmarks().get(end.getName()).getText());
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks~
Regarding the follow-up operation, I have replied to you on apose.com.
Looking forward to your kind reply. https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-can-i-get-all-the-text-content-before-a-bookmark-or-node/234376